# React + Mui v5: Do I need to use StyledEngineProvider for sx prop?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using react + materialui V5 (MUI) and only the sx prop for the styling solution.

Do I need to use the StyledEngineProvider as a wrapper for my ThemeProvider ?

Thank you!

```
<StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
   (...themeProvider)
   (...routes)
</StyledEngineProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using just "sx" prop you don't need to use StyledEngineProvider wrapper. It's used when you're app uses JSS and emotion styles.